# Create multiple pages/sub site from one node type

Tags: theming, nodes, panels, views, distributions

I am fairly new to drupal and finishing up my first large site. I am using the panopoly profile.

For this site I need to create this massive content type. It would be used to generate about 5 pages from the nodes content and they each need their own template/layout. Essentially its a child site.

How can I create multiple pages from a single node type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spliting a node into multiple pages](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95416/spliting-a-node-into-multiple-pages)

Comment: Possibly could use Panelizer with Variants with certain conditions. Does each of the 5 pages have its own URL - if so then this would be feasible with Panelizer.

Comment: Not a duplicate I am not asking abour pagination or books. I know about both already.

Yes each has their own url. We decided to use page manager and panels to do it. My co-worker figured out how to do this this morning and showed me.